# PHP PDO: Set FireBird connection timeout

Tags: php, timeout, pdo, firebird

I'm connecting to a FireBird database, which works fine when the database is online. When the server is offline, the user gets an max execution time passed error.

Therefore I want to surround the connection statement with a try catch and set the timeout to 10 seconds. But I can't find the right attribute to do so. The default `ATTR_TIMEOUT` doesn't seem to work. Can anyone tell me if this is possible with PDO and FireBird?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about PHP / PDO but there is `ConnectionTimeout` parameter in the firebird.conf file you could try. The default value is 180 seconds (quote from conf file):

```
# ----------------------------
# Client Connection Settings (Basic)
#
# Seconds to wait before concluding an attempt to connect has failed.
#
# Type: integer
#
#ConnectionTimeout = 180
```

If your FireBird server is not in the same server where the PHP script runs and you don't have firebird.conf file on the "PHP server", then try to put one into same directory where the fbclient dll is. Or if there is `FIREBIRD` enviroment variable defined, then into the directory that var points to.

Comment: Not what I was looking for but it is as close as it gets for this problem, thank you